# Acumatica grid navigation link won't do anything

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add a simple navigation link to a details grid of CR Cases on a custom screen with a header of Support Accounts.  The grid contains cases for the account, and I'm trying to add a navigation link on the case ID to open an individual case screen.  It shows the link in the column, but it will not open the individual Case screen.  Please let me know what I'm missing.  I simply added a link command of Cases_ViewDetails similar to what I've done on other link columns.  Shouldn't that be enough?  I also tried replacing the default PXSelector attribute for the CaseCD to be a PXNavigateSelector, and that also didn't work.

v2019 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article https://blog.zaletskyy.com/post/2017/03/10/post100 pointed me in the right direction. Adding an action with the correct name finally allowed the event handler to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the attribute AllowEdit = True on the field on the screen? That may pop the link.

Comment: There's no AllowEdit option on the screen/field options, and if I add it to the .aspx manually and Generate, Acumatica removes it.

Comment: Ok, I was able to add AllowEdit = "true" manually to .aspx now, but link still does nothing.

Comment: Can you post your Link command code? Also, for using the selector in a grid, you have the pxselector in the declared in the row template of the grid?